# display css value for width and height display dynamically , Jquery Javascript alert function

Tags: jquery

```
<tr><td><img src="images/C003.jpg" alt="title" class="OrignialImage" /></td></tr> 

.OrignialImage
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

By using jquery, could we get width value from css class dynamically ?
Is there any way to get width value and height value dynamically, Please let me know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/ZsTAt/

```
$('.OrignialImage').css('height')
$('.OrignialImage').css('width')
$('.OrignialImage').height()
$('.OrignialImage').width()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following jquery apis:

- [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)
- [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
- [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Example:

```
$(".OrignialImage").width();
$(".OrignialImage").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has multiple ways to get the css height and width of an object.  The simplest is `$(<selector>).height()` and `$(<selector>).width()`

If you want the height and width with the padding included then you can use `$(<selector>).innerHeight()` and `$(<selector>).innerWidth()` respectively.

And if you want the height and width with the padding and margin included then you can use `$(<selector>).outerHeight()` and `$(<selector>).outerWidth()`

And if you really wanted to you could use `$(<selector>).css('height')` or `$(<selector>).css('width')`

For more information on these methods you can look at the jQuery documentation here http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/